# Objective C : dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath: returns exception

Tags: ios, objective-c, storyboard, uitableview

I made my prototype cell in the storyboard and setted its identifier, but when I call

```
cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"ident" forIndexPath:indexPath];
```

in my `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method I get exception:

```
 unable to dequeue a cell with identifier ident - must register a nib or a class for the identifier or connect a prototype cell in a storyboard
```

Now, I know that, if I declare a prototype cell in storyboard, I don't need to explicitly register it.
then...Why this exception?

Update:
I post two images with show problem:
[image]
[image]

Comment: did u set ur cell identifer in storyboard?

Comment: yes, i update answer with images

Comment: where is the `UITableViewCell` with identifier `voce`? This might be cause the Exception

Comment: no, it works (already tried) If you read the exception below you read `cella_opzioni_menu`

Answer (score 1):

try doing these..

remove  these..

```
NSString *identificatore=@"voce";
```

and do these..

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath;
{
    static NSString *yourcellidentifier=@"cella_opzioni_menu";//here write the cell identifier you gave in storyboard..

    cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:yourcellidentifier];

    if(cell == nil)
    {
         ........
    }

    .
    .
    .

}
```

i hope it helps..

Comment: already tried: it gives me a nil value......